# How to stream opencv frames to a webpage in my network?

Tags: opencv, stream, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to use Raspberry pi to send video adjusted with OpenCV effects (a simple color conversion now but would like to do much more) from PiCamera to a webpage in my network. I tried using PiCamera 4.10 Webstreaming instructions [https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#web-streaming](https://stackoverflow.com) but could not figure out how to adjust frames with opencv prior to sending them so I created another approach of launching a thread that generates the openCV adjusted frames. It does not work but I know it is sending something to the webpage - just not  the frames I want...below is the code...can you help me figure out what is wrong please.

```
import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
from http import server
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import time
import imutils
from threading import Thread

PAGE="""\
<html>
<head>
<title>picamera</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="stream.mjpg" width="640" height="480" />
</body>
</html>
"""

class StreamingOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.condition = Condition()

    def send_frame(self, buf):
        with self.condition:
            self.frame = buf
            self.condition.notify_all()

class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print(self.path)
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/index.html':
            content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', 0)
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
                while True:
                    with output.condition:
                        output.condition.wait()
                        frame = output.frame
                    self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(frame)
                    self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(
                    'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                    self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True

def task ():
    while True:
        frame = vs.read()
        opencv_screen_size = (240,320)
        frame = cv.resize(frame, opencv_screen_size)
        img = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        byte_img = img.tobytes()
        output.send_frame(byte_img)

output = StreamingOutput()
vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=True).start()
time.sleep(1)
thread = Thread(target=task)
thread.start()
try:
    address = ('', 8000)
    server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
    server.serve_forever()

finally:
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```